# Proving surjectivity of $z\exp(z)$ on the complex plane.

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function

I am trying to prove the surjectivity of $f(z)= z \exp(z)$ on the complex plane. I know this question already has answers here, but they always use Little Picard's theorem which I am not allowed to use.

So far I have thought of the following: Certainly, $0 \in f(\mathbb{C})$. Let $0\neq w \in \mathbb{C}$. As $\exp$ is surjective onto $\mathbb{C} \backslash \{0\} $ we may write $w=\exp(a+ib)$ with real $a,b$. Now I am trying to prove that we can write $a+ib= u+\exp(u)$ for $u \in \mathbb{C}$, because then $\exp(a+ib)=\exp(u)\exp (\exp(u))=v\exp(v) $ for $v= \exp(u)$, again using the surjectivity of $\exp$. So basically, I have shifted the problem to showing that $z+ \exp(z)$ is surjective onto $\mathbb{C}$. Here is where I got stuck.

Any hint on how to proceed would be very much appreciated.

Comment: The question is equivalent to the fact that the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) is defined over the whole $\Bbb C$. So you could look at the references in the Wikipedia page.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y \in \mathbb C^{\ast}$ be fixed and $g(z) = y \exp(-z)$.  Then there is an $\alpha \in \mathbb R$, $\lvert \alpha \rvert > \pi+1$, such that the horizontal strip $$ S = \{ z \mid \lvert \operatorname{Im}(z)  - \alpha \rvert < \pi\}$$ of width $2\pi$ is contained in its image under $g$.  That is, $S \subset g(S)$.  Note that $g$ is injective on $S$ and that $g(S)$ is the complex plane minus some ray.  The argument of this ray is determined by $\alpha \pmod {2 \pi}$. The inverse of $g$ is given by $$g^{-1}(z) = \log(y) - \log(z)$$ for some suitable branch of $\log$, and maps into $S$.  In particular $g^{-1}(S) \subset S$ and $g^{-1}$ is a contraction on $S$.  This means that $g^{-1}$ has exactly one fixed point $z_0$ in $S$.  This $z_0$ is also a fixed point of $g$ which means that $z_0 \exp(z_0) = y$.

Comment: Is there an easy way to see that $log$ is a contraction?

Comment: There is some $k < 1$ such that $\lvert \log’(z) \rvert < k$ on $S$.